# Customising heatmaply hover in R Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, hover, heatmaply

I have a `plotlyOutput` heatmap in a R Shiny app, which I render through `heatmaply`.

When I hover the mouse on the heatmap I get a popup saying

```
Row - [rowname] 
Column - [columnname]
Value - xxxxx
```

How would I go about customising this to a custom string?

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example?

Comment: @bretauv there is no need for an additional parameter. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can overwrite the default [hovertemplate](https://plotly.com/r/reference/#scatter-hovertemplate) via `style()`:

```
library(heatmaply)
library(datasets)

heatmaply(mtcars) |> style(hovertemplate = paste0("X: %{x}<extra></extra>"))
```